# Why are my animations different compared to phone/tablet (density) and how to prevent it?

Tags: android, resolution, objectanimator

When using an ObjectAnimator to move an item I get different results due to the density difference between my devices. How would I go about making these independent from density?

```
ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(clockLayout, "translationY", 0f, -80f);
                anim1.setDuration(300);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way I found is to add a dimension using dpi:

so in your values dimens.xml file:

```
<dimen name="delta_y">80dp</dimen>
```

and then you can turn this into a float in your activity with:

```
float deltaY = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.delta_y);

ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(clockLayout, "translationY", 0f, -deltaY);
```

Comment: hey trying to get my rep to 50 so I can comment else where, can you accept and upvote the answer. Thanks